# React Native bottom bar tab change route variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

[image]
I want to build a bottom tab bar that is same in every screen but I want bottom Tabs' route change.
ex. In Screen1 in bottom tab bar Tab route in 'Screen2' and when navigate in Screen2 then tab route change from Screen2 to Screen3.
But always appear the same bottom tab bar.

One idea is to create bottom tab bar with Tab route {ScreenRoute} and in every Screen change ScreenRoute variable.
ex.
In Screen1 var ScreenRoute = 'Screen2' ,
In Screen2 var ScreenRoute = 'Screen3'
etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `tabPress` listener and prevent the default navigation event using the `preventDefault` function. Furthermore, use a state to indicate the current route. Use a reference to the `NavigationContainer` in order to navigate to a desired screen.

Here is a minimal example.

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const navigationRef = React.useRef();
  const [routeName, setRouteName] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      onReady={() => {
        const currentRoute = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute();
        setRouteName(currentRoute.name);
      }}>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="A"
          component={StackA}
          listeners={{
            tabPress: (e) => {             
              e.preventDefault()
              if (routeName === "ScreenA") {
                setRouteName("ScreenA2");
                navigationRef.current.navigate("ScreenA2")
              } else if (routeName === "ScreenA2") {
                setRouteName("ScreenA3");
                navigationRef.current.navigate("ScreenA3")
              } else {
                setRouteName("ScreenA")
                navigationRef.current.navigate("ScreenA")
              }
            },
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The navigators and screens are defined as follows.

```js
function ScreenA() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>ScreenA</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function ScreenA2() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>ScreenA2</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function ScreenA3() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>ScreenA3</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function StackA() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="ScreenA" component={ScreenA} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ScreenA2" component={ScreenA2} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ScreenA3" component={ScreenA3} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

[Here is a little snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/bottom-tabs-navigator-%7C-react-navigation).

The first press on the tab will navigate to `ScreenA2`, the second press will navigate to `ScreenA3`, the third press will start on `ScreenA` again.

Comment: Ιt works! I try also to add a second Tab Screen and StackB but didn't work with error "The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload was not handled by any navigator. What changes should I  do?